# Get value from a website using Yún and a RPi

Tags: arduino-yun

I have a project that requires opening a door remotely. I'm using an arduino Yún and a raspberry pi.
 I have a switch connected to the RPI and i'm sending it's value to a web server. How can I get the value from the website to the arduino, so that it can process it and see if an order to open the door is issued?

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: Do you want to do it from the Linux portion or the AVR portion of the Yun?

Comment: I want to check the remote value (located on a web-site) using AVR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the [Process](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Process) library that comes with the IDE.

That allows you to execute commands on the Linux portion of the Yun from within your Arduino code, and get data back from it.

You use that class to execute the `curl` command in Linux to fetch the content of a web page and return that content to the AVR code where you can deal with it.

If the content of the web page is complex it may be worth passing the output of `curl` through some other Linux based commands first (such as `grep` and `cut` or `awk`) to clean it up and reduce the amount of text you have to deal with at the AVR end.